# Website is formatted differently on different screens despite percentage information

Tags: html, css

Although i used percentages instead of absolute pixel values, the website looks different on my 13.3 inch screen with a resolution of 2560 x 1600 pixels than on my 27 inch screen with a resolution of 5120 x 2880 pixels.

[Photo of the website on the 13.3 inch screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXIkt.jpg)

[Photo of the website on the 27 inch screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66iA0.jpg)

As you can see, the height of the black bar (i.e. the empty area) between the two rows of images is different. I suspect that it is in some way due to the images. Do you have any idea how I can fix this?

```css
html {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  background-color: black;
  min-width: 800px;
  max-width: 1600px;
  min-height: 1024px;
  max-height: 8000px;
}

p.h1 {
  color: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, blue, yellow, red, purple);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  font-size: 170px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 3.90625%
}

p.h2 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -8%;
  font-size: 50px;
}

#eins {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5.3125%;
  top: 77.21518987341773%;
}

#eins:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

#zwei {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5.3125%;
  top: 77.21518987341773%;
}

#zwei:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

#drei {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5.3125%;
  top: 147.5%;
}

#drei:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

#vier {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5.3125%;
  top: 147.5%;
}

#vier:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

#fünf {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5.3125%;
  top: 217.7848102%;
}

#fünf:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

#sechs {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5.3125%;
  top: 217.7848102%;
}

#sechs:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

#sieben {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5.3125%;
  top: 288.0696204%;
}

#sieben:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

#acht {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5.3125%;
  top: 288.0696204%;
}

#acht:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

#neun {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5.3125%;
  top: 358.3544306%;
}

#neun:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

#zehn {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5.3125%;
  top: 358.3544306%;
}

#zehn:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

#elf {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5.3125%;
  top: 428.6392408%;
}

#elf:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

#zwölf {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5.3125%;
  top: 428.6392408%;
}

#zwölf:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

#dreizehn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5.3125%;
  top: 498.924051%;
}

#dreizehn:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

#vierzehn {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5.3125%;
  top: 498.924051%;
}

#vierzehn:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <p class="h1">Selected Work</p>
  <p class="h2">Hier steht etwas: etwas.</p>
  <a href="Fotos/DSC02316.JPG" onclick="FensterOeffnen(this.href); return false"> <img id="eins" src="Fotos/DSC02316.JPG" width="41.25%" height="auto"> </a>
  <a href="Fotos/DSC01451.JPG" onclick="FensterOeffnen(this.href); return false"> <img id="zwei" src="Fotos/DSC01451.JPG" width="41.25%" height="auto"> </a>
  <a href="Fotos/DSC00700.jpeg" onclick="FensterOeffnen(this.href); return false"> <img id="drei" src="Fotos/DSC00700.jpeg" width="41.25%" height="auto"> </a>
  <a href="Fotos/DSC00750.JPG" onclick="FensterOeffnen(this.href); return false"> <img id="vier" src="Fotos/DSC00750.JPG" width="41.25%" height="auto"> </a>
  <a href="Fotos/schmetterling.jpg" onclick="FensterOeffnen(this.href); return false"> <img id="fünf" src="Fotos/schmetterling.jpg" width="41.25%" height="auto"> </a>
  <a href="Fotos/DSC02034.JPG" onclick="FensterOeffnen(this.href); return false"> <img id="sechs" src="Fotos/DSC02034.JPG" width="41.25%" height="auto"> </a>
  <a href="Fotos/Wasserfall 1_Fotor.jpg" onclick="FensterOeffnen(this.href); return false"> <img id="sieben" src="Fotos/Wasserfall 1_Fotor.jpg" width="41.25%" height="auto"> </a>
  <a href="Fotos/DSC02018.jpeg" onclick="FensterOeffnen(this.href); return false"> <img id="acht" src="Fotos/DSC02018.jpeg" width="41.25%" height="auto"> </a>
  <a href="Fotos/DSC00414.JPG" onclick="FensterOeffnen(this.href); return false"> <img id="neun" src="Fotos/DSC00414.JPG" width="41.25%" height="auto"> </a>
  <a href="Fotos/DSC01337.JPG" onclick="FensterOeffnen(this.href); return false"> <img id="zehn" src="Fotos/DSC01337.JPG" width="41.25%" height="auto"> </a>
  <a href="Fotos/DSC01384.JPG" onclick="FensterOeffnen(this.href); return false"> <img id="elf" src="Fotos/DSC01384.JPG" width="41.25%" height="auto"> </a>
  <a href="Fotos/DSC01343.JPG" onclick="FensterOeffnen(this.href); return false"> <img id="zwölf" src="Fotos/DSC01343.JPG" width="41.25%" height="auto"> </a>
  <a href="Fotos/DSC00980.JPG" onclick="FensterOeffnen(this.href); return false"> <img id="dreizehn" src="Fotos/DSC00980.JPG" width="41.25%" height="auto"> </a>
  <a href="Fotos/DSC00974.JPG" onclick="FensterOeffnen(this.href); return false"> <img id="vierzehn" src="Fotos/DSC00974.JPG" width="41.25%" height="auto"> </a>
</main>
```

Comment: try to learn **Bootstrap** I'm sure it makes it easy for you; https://getbootstrap.com

Comment: use  vh instead of %.

Comment: thank you, but it still looks the same.

Comment: Not positive but it could have something to do with the height auto you have on all of your Images. If your looking for maximum control over placement and spacing look into display grid.